# Get a zip file from a Linux server to a unix server using curl

Tags: linux, unix, curl

I am trying to get a file from a linux server.  I can ping the server from the unix server.

I am using a "sh" command and my script looks like the following.

```
sh -c '/usr/local/bin/curl -# -d -u user:password http://13.1.2.310/tmp/allsig
s/2015-10-05.zip'
```

I am get the below error message.  Any ideal on what I am doing wrong?

```
<html>
<body bgColor="#FFFFFF">
  <div style="text-align: center">
<h3>AppServer has encountered a fatal runtime error</h3>
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
  <b>mod_bravoconnector.c Database Connection Failed!
</body>
```

Comment: You aren't necessarily doing anything wrong, that problem is on the server side, not the curl client side.

Comment: What do you mean by that.  Is there something on the client side I need to look at?

Comment: sorry i meant *server side  not client side

Comment: Yeah, the server program is generating that database connection failed error, if you can get in there you might be able to do something about it.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for responding.  I am confuse on what you are saying.  Where do I go look.  Are you talking about the unix server or the linux server?  What do I need to change?

Comment: Do you also get that error when you use `wget` instead of `curl`?

Comment: I will give that a try

Comment: I am still open to why the curl is not working

Comment: The machine that I am working on does not have wget installed.  So I have to use curl